# Entity framework - load children and sort for datagridview

Tags: sorting, frameworks, datagridview, load, entity

I have winform application with master/detail datagridviews. I use explicit loading to load child entities on master positionchanged event.

```
private void masterBindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var master = masterBindingSource.Current as Master;
       if ((master != null) && (!master.children.IsLoaded))
       {                 
           master.children.Load();
       }               

   }
```

My only problem is that I need sort children according one field. This doesnt work - master.children.OrderByDescending(c => c.sortfield); 
Does anyone konw how to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so seems it s not possible to sort it with load method. i can do that with query but then is isloaded property always false - it is set on true only with load method call.